# Каскадное удаление в Hibernate зависимых сущностей

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-jpa

Есть две сущности со связью `m2o`, я никак не могу понять как аннотацией настроить каскадное удаление всех дочерних сущностей при удалении родительской. Есть подозрение что возможно я их изначально как-то неправильно создал. Как DAO использую Spring DATA JPA, то-есть пользуюсь методом `deleteById(ID id)` который уже есть в `CrudRepository`.

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Site {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    private String country;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    private String region;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Sector {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Site site;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;
}
```

Если добавить в аннотацию `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` будет следующее исключение:

```
2019-05-27 17:16:10.683  INFO 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] f.k.escalade.controllers.SiteController  : DELETE site by ID : 1
Hibernate: select site0_.id as id1_2_0_, site0_.country as country2_2_0_, site0_.description as descript3_2_0_, site0_.name as name4_2_0_, site0_.region as region5_2_0_ from site site0_ where site0_.id=?
Hibernate: delete from site where id=?
2019-05-27 17:16:10.696  WARN 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
2019-05-27 17:16:10.696 ERROR 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: update or delete on table "site" violates foreign key constraint "fkn2x370i2i28hqnqof5ejjo4ou" on table "sector"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "sector".
2019-05-27 17:16:10.697  INFO 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2019-05-27 17:16:10.700 ERROR 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019-05-27 17:16:10.711 ERROR 9350 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fkn2x370i2i28hqnqof5ejjo4ou]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "site" violates foreign key constraint "fkn2x370i2i28hqnqof5ejjo4ou" on table "sector"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "sector".
```

Впрочем если не добавить, то будет тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в сущность Site добавить поле:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Sector> sectors;
```

И из siteRepository выполнить метод deleteById

Comment: Да спасибо, помогло. Пришлось делать двунаправленные связи.

Comment: Правда теперь проблема в том что не получается обновить сущность

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить параметр `cascade` к текущей аннотации:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
```

Или задать отдельно аннотацией:

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
```

---

Попробуйте использовать такую аннотацию:

```
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Возможно один из этих вариантов устарел, нет возможности проверить.

Comment: Я уже пробовал, но почему то они не работают.

Comment: @Artem где же тогда в вопросе описание попыток и, самое главное, полученных ошибок?

Comment: Извиняюсь что не указал, просто я уже столько всего попробовал что сам во всех этих методах немного запутался. Но сейчас отредактирую какое исключение вылетает если сделать как вы советуете.

Comment: @Artem добавил ещё один вариант.